# Intuition Behind Principle of Superposition

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

What's the intuition, and if any, logical argument behind the principle of superposition of electric fields and forces?

*The force with which two charges interact is not changed by the presence of a third charge*

This is a pretty significant result in electrostatics, which I'm not able to predict using logical arguments such as symmetry, among many other possibilities. So, what's the intuition behind it? Why does it work, and how can we deduce it theoretically?

Comment: In quantum mechanics electrostatic interactions can be thought of as charges passing virtual photons between each other, photons of course do not interact with each other so would be uneffected by virtual photons coming from a third charge. Though I don't particularly like that answer

Comment: Research? See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-superposition-theorem). Also [Intuitive explanation of the waves superposition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114933) and [Is the superposition principle universal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47443)